# What do I do with an opinion-only answer?

Tags: discussion

There are some questions on this site which provoke opinion-based answers (i.e. [Are there any redeeming characters in Game of Thrones/SOIAF?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/are-there-any-redeeming-characters-in-game-of-thrones-soiaf) - which has 13 answers!).

There are some answers which address this well:

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3268/21267
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3279/21267

and some who inherently stray into opinion-territory:

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3500/21267
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4229/21267

I have to point out that it is not the fault of the answerers - the OP has asked an open-ended and opinion-soliciting question (it just becomes "I think Jon Snow is good", "no I think Victarion is good" etc.).

**Here's the problem:**
I wouldn't flag the entire question, as there are some good answers which do not go into specific opinions. There are however some answers which are primarily opinion-based and in my opinion something *may* need to be done.

**Solutions:**

1. I flag the answer (but there's no appropriate flag choice)
2. I down-vote/forgo up-vote
3. Something else

**What is the correct course of action if I see an *answer* which I think is primarily opinion-based?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the FAQ

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

- If you think that a question is itself opinion-based (or prone to generating opinion-based answers) mark it to "close" and see if your fellow site users agree.
- If you think that an answer is too opinion-based, downvote it and explain to the author why you've done so.

Comment: I could flag the question, but I just don't want to flag the whole question because it has some good answers. What do I do about the **answers** which are opinion-based?

Comment: @Mooz - Downvote them and explain to the user why.

Comment: @Mooz The fact that a question has good answers does not make it a good question.

Comment: @Phantom42 The fact that a question has good answers _does show_ that there is some merit in it.

Comment: There are lots of interesting questions which do not meet the standards of a SE site.

Comment: @SQB Having merit does not mean it's a good question or a good fit for the site. [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26773/is-edward-cullen-a-pedophile), for example, has a -6 score and has been closed as non-constructive (an outdated close reason now, to be fair) but the answer has a +14 score.

Comment: Similarly, [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/are-there-any-redeeming-characters-in-game-of-thrones-soiaf) has both a high question score and answer scores, but is currently on its way to being closed as opinion based.

Answer (score 4):

Some kinds of opinion-based questions and answers are OK.

This is covered in depth on the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) SE Blog post so I won't go into excessive detail here.

The key word in the "Primarily Opinion Based" close reason in this context is **Primarily**.  Obviously this isn't a binary distinction, and there are all kinds of grey areas in between.  An opinion-based answer may well be backed up by solid evidence sourced from canonical texts; despite the fact that the final conclusion may be opinion-based, if the weight of such evidence is strong enough, then it is a good answer.  A bad opinion-based answer on the other hand is solely or mostly comprised of opinion, with little (or poor) evidence to support the conclusions (if indeed there are any conclusions).

So what I'm saying is that you shouldn't look for a hard-and-fast ruling on this, but instead make your own best judgement on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I do like the concept of "make up your own mind, using educated ideas and case-by-case basis" etc; but does that apply to **answers** as well? And what close-reason should I use?